# Дубликаты в базе mysql при двойном клике

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Итак, коротко о проблеме:
На сайте есть кнопка спасибо под каждым постом и время от времени в базе появляются две "спасибы" к одному посту от одного пользователя. Я так понимаю это происходит при быстром двойном клике...

Как вижу решение:

1. добавить составной уникальный ключ

   ALTER TABLE `karma`
   ADD UNIQUE `user_post` (`user_id`, `post_id`)
   ;
2. Лочить таблицу на время запроса

   LOCK TABLES karma WRITE;
   ...
   UNLOCK TABLES;
3. Сделать таймаут перед запросом

   usleep(250000);

Пока установил костыль из 3 варианта.

Второй вариант не стал использовать, т.к. не совсем понятна команда UNLOCK TABLES она разблокирует все таблицы что были залочены ранее(например кроном)? или те что залочены в данном скрипте?

Интересует первый вариант. Как установить уникальную ключ-пару если в базе уже есть дубли?

Comment: Если вы не можете добавить уникальное поле (не автоинкрементное), то попробуйте на сайте отправку сделать средствами js и блокировать кнопку после нажатия

Comment: удалить эти дубли и повесить индекс. если в таблице связи это единственные два поля, то тогда вообще составной первичный ключ и на первое место поставить post_id. Дабы очистить от дублей, самое простое будет претащить distinct выборку во временную таблицу, очистить данные, добавить ключ/индекс и вернуть данные назад. Либо добавить инкрементный столбец, и удалить дубли с максимальынм инкрементом.. А если инкремент имеется, то просто удалить с максимальным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант самый адекватный разумеется.

И так, запрос для добавления индекса у вас уже есть, в таком случае, вам нужно оставить по одной такой записи в таблице на каждого user-a и post соответственно.

Запрос для удаления дублей:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_karma as (
    SELECT min(id) FROM karma GROUP BY user_id, post_id
);

DELETE FROM karma WHERE karma.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM temp_karma
);
```

Это оставит по одной, уникальной записи для ключа (user_id, post_id) в вашей таблице karma.